# How do I hide a variable value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, hidden

I am currently working on a JavaScript project and know that JavaScript source code is accessible through the browser. In the code, I have a variable that stores a secret string that is used by the program. However, I do not want others to view the source code and find out the value of this variable. **Is there a way to hide the value of a variable?** Or is it possible to change the variable value after? For instance, change the actual source code to set the variable to a different value? This variable is only used the first time an image is loaded so it would be okay to remove it altogether if that is possible.

Comment: That's totally impossible; the attacker has full control over the debugger.

Comment: Whatever you're doing sounds insecure. Reconsider your approach.

Comment: @SLaks, How do an attacker inject a debugger keyword on a `(function(){ const x = prompt("give me a secret"); ... })()`?

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho: By setting a breakpoint in devtools.

Comment: @SLaks, It is not possible to access client browsers devtools without them notice the browser console is open. If you mean on client side the attacker must have access to server to do the insider job. What you say is totally impossible.

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho: This is talking about the browser / client, not the server.

Comment: Then it is not possible attackers come home and open clients console.

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho: He's asking to hide a value from the user, not an external attacker.

Comment: A value from the user can be a secret string from a `prompt("password")` that should be fairly secure in the most browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot hide JavaScript content from a programmer.  They can always open the developer console and get all your variables.

What's worse, they can use said console to directly bypass any JavaScript validation, so it cannot be your primary security.

If it is something you must hide or secure against, you must look into a server side solution.

Comment: There is fairly safe CDN servers where to put the code, so we can exclude manipulation ones uploaded. At client side the programmers don't come home and open your console. Because this answer is accepted the post owner did not *have a variable that stores a secret string*. It was probably a hardcoded string, not a secret string.

Comment: We're not talking about securing source code.  We're talking about securing variable values.  That is literally impossible.  Getting JS variable value is trivially easy.

Comment: by just say someone is *plain wrong* does not make sense to anything you say. I have not claimed that *Javascript variable is "impossible"*! I could claim that *Javascript variable is **possible** to store a secret* - but that would not be possible because your kind work in teams.

Comment: This answer should be removed because it is just a "fact" based on "a sense of security" and if questioned it seem to be based on wild imaginations with no fundamental understanding about how browser console work.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is run on the client, so I don't think this is going to possible. Anything that you need to be kept secret is going to need to be server side.

Comment: Javascript is isomorphic so it run on server too

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is impossible at the moment.

But there's a JavaScript proposal **[Function implementation hiding](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-function-implementation-hiding)**, which – as the name suggests – hides function implementation from being observed.  The proposal originated in mid-2019, and is in stage 2 (out of 4) at the moment. I personally doubt that it will ever be part of the standard, but if it does, in theory you could hide the secret inside of the body of a hidden function:

```js
function fetchData() {
  "sensitive"; // ← the proposal

  const SECRET = "VGhlIG1lc3NhZ2UgaXM6IFIyeHZjbmtnZEc4Z1ZXdHlZV2x1WmZDZmg3cnduNGVt";

  return fetch(DATA_URL, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${SECRET}`,
    },
  });
}
```

The `SECRET` variable cannot be inspected through debugger or through `fetchData.toString()`. However, the value of `Authorization` header is visible in a network tab in console, so the whole thing is inappropriate for this use case.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is client side, and there isn't really anyway to hide the code.

**What you can do:** Prevent common users from seeing it (aka making it harder to find)

My suggestion is to encrypt the data using some sort of cipher (preferably not an online encryption tool).  This stops *most lazy* people from seeing it.

(Assuming no one is actually trying to find this mysterious value)

Answer (score -3):

Well, you can just put the entire code into one function and then execute it after that in the same script. That helped me.