# Cloud Functions hidden after uploading to github?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, google-cloud-functions

I have downloaded node.js, and have created the firebase-function files at the website directory (firebase.json, the functions folder and others). 
If I was to write javascript cloud functions inside the project/functions/index.js file, it won't be private when I upload it to my Github repository for my static website. (something.github.io)

So how would I go about calling the firebase cloud functions in my index.js to my static website without uploading the index.js (to keep certain functions private)?

Edit:
I understand now that there are environmental variables, but how can I incorporate that with Github Pages website with firebase Admin SDK and cloud functions?

How do I upload my GitHub pages project and still link my client-side to the environmental variables? Would I need to upload my index.js containing my cloud functions? But also doesn't upload the index.js defeat the purpose of the client not being able to see the functions/data?

The comment below mentioned a software calledHeroku, what exactly is the purpose of it when I already have GitHub and firebase interacting with my website and database?

Also I saw a method of using dotenv, to create a .env file to put secret data (such as API keys) and use gitignore to prevent the file being uploaded? Would that be able to work on Github Pages, and if so, would the client be able to see the .env? And if they can't, can the client-server website link it to the .env even if it isn't pushed to Github

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use of [environment variables](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786). Essentially, say you had an API key of `12345`. And you had a function as such:

```js
async function fetchResults() {
    await fetch("myapi.com/lookup?key=12345")
}
```

You could do instead:

```js
async function fetchResults() {
    await fetch("myapi.com/lookup?key=${process.env.API_KEY}")
}
```

The environment variable is kept on your machine so it never goes to GitHub, hence allowing you to expose the code as open source while maintaining confidentiality of your sensitive keys.

**Edit:** So I reread your question and I see you're talking about publishing to GitHub pages. The key thing to note is that anything that is hosted *client-side* the user will be able to see. GitHub Pages only hosts the "client" portion of your application. So if your client (browser) website makes an API call to `myapi.com/lookup?key=12345`, they will be able to see it no matter what, since it's their browser making a request and they can see anything their browser does.

However, the best practice here is to write *server-side* code to run your application as well. For this, you can use what I suggested above, where you add environment variables to whichever server you use to host (for example, you can do this easily with `[Zeit Now][2]` or [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)). That way, you can share your code but your environment variables stay secret on the machine that runs your server-side code.

Comment: I'm still confused on how {process.env.API_KEY} can still retrieve the variable. Is my computer with the project, technically the server? How could I link the environmental variables from my local disk to the functions in my Github project. Sorry for any troubles or misunderstanding, i'm really new at this.

Comment: That's a good question. I made an edit to my post. Please let me know if that resolves any confusion.

Comment: If I were to use dotenv npm to create a .env file with my environmental variables and use gitignore to hide that .env file when uploading to github pages, would it appear on the client-side still; or would that be a solution to appropriately hiding the API key? Or by doing this, am I unable to retrieve the environmental errors?

Comment: Anything that is hosted on GitHub pages is considered client-side, and technically, anything that is client-side is visible to any user of your site. So it's not possible to hide any keys client-side. There's no concept of environment variables for client-side apps. For the code that runs on the server, this is where my solution would work. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890783/how-do-i-hide-a-variable-value-in-javascript) may be helpful to clarify what I mean.